# MongoDB Cast Error when updating nested array

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

When I try and update an element in a nested array, I'm getting a Cast Error. In my document, `accounts` is an array and I'm trying to update an individual account by its id, hence the id filter. This gives the error:

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value ":id" (type string)
```

Below is how I'm trying to update the document, why this error is coming?

```
Document.updateOne(
        {
            "globalProperties.email": req.headers.email,
            "globalProperties.accounts._id": req.params.id                
       },
        {
            $set: {
                "globalProperties.account.$.name": "some string",

                "globalProperties.account.$.followers": "some number",
            },
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `req.params.id` is not a valid ObjectId. You can first check if it is valid or not.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id); // should be valid to update the document
```

You need to make sure that it has to be ObjectId in order for MongoDB to find, and update the document.

Comment: Do you mean I'm not sending an ObjectId that's in the database, or is it something else? I've verified that the id being sent in the request parameters is an id of an object in the database.